# LVM failure recovery

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, ext3, ext4

We have an server PC with "intel matrix storage manager" raid (or maybe 'fake' raid) controller. Firstly there were one RAID-1 with two equal seagate disks of 1TB size. We've installed ubuntu server there, partitioned disk with standard partitions. Then we ran out of space and bought another two equal seagate disks (of different model) for second RAID-1. On a new disks we've decided to use LVM.

Everything was fine until this week, when both disks in a first RAID-1 started failing read/write operations. S.M.A.R.T. tests failed for both of them. We've rebooted the server, it started fine. However, we started to move sensitive data to second (we hoped good) RAID-1. For backups couple of new logical partitions were created. At some time it failed input/output operation again and we had to reboot server PC. Then we've decided not to use faulty drive anymore and just start with ubuntu live CD. Then package `lvm2` was installed right on running live CD ubuntu, then standard `pvscan`, `vgscan` discovered only ONE logical partition instead of SIX. After googling around we've found the lvm backup config file and done `vgcfgrestore` so all logical partitions become visible. Unfortunately, all other partitions became un-mountable. Mount says:

> mount: you must specify the filesystem type

or

> mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/vg-backup_opt,
>
> ```
>   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
>
>   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
>
>   dmesg | tail  or so
> ```

`dmesg | tail`

> [96233.605251] EXT3-fs (dm-3): error: can't find ext3 filesystem on dev dm-3.
>
> [96233.664882] EXT4-fs (dm-3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
>
> [96233.784763] EXT2-fs (dm-3): error: can't find an ext2 filesystem on dev dm-3

Then we've tried several things such as `mke2fs -S`, `testdisk`, `sleuthkit`. Nothing helps.

The most disappointing thing is that among partitions that have been lost only three were really new, others were created about a month ago.

Can't imagine what can be done now. Please help.

Comment: Ubuntu live CD may not have drivers for Intel fakeraid. Try a different boot CD.

Comment: I suppose that's not the case because the only discovered for the first time logical partition can be mounted fine.

Comment: Are you able to get `/etc/lvm*` from the first RAID1 drives? If so - copy it to your LiveCD setup and try to mount the LVM2 partitions.

Comment: Yes, we got about 5 historical LVM configurations. We've tried them all, with no success :( Moreover, we've tried to make an image from logical volume and then use `foremost` to recover, no success again. Like all data is zeroed there. Now we're thinking about outsourcing to some data recovery agency, but there are holidays in Russia...